# Segmentation fault using pthreads while performing addition?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am writing a program which basically performs addition on two values given by the user. This is my first attempt at multi-threading. Whenever I enter the first value, it gives me "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error.

```
void *printSum();

void main()
{
    int *a,*b,*add;
    printf("Enter first number: ");
    scanf("%d",a);                    //error here
    printf("Enter second number: ");
    scanf("%d",b);

    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, printSum, NULL);
}

void *printSum()
{
    int *a,*b,*add;
    *add = *a + *b;
    printf("Sum = %d", *add);
    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

I have initialized the same variables in printSum() because otherwise, it gives me an error saying that the variables are undeclared. What should I do?

Comment: The pointers in `printSum` are local to that function, and haven't been initialized, so they point to random places in memory.  Did you want to make them global, or pass the values from `main` to the thread?

Comment: Defining variables of the same name in different functions does not make them the same variable.  Function arguments are there so you can pass variables into them.  also, `*&a` --> `a`.

Comment: Also, the `scanf`s in `main` are wrong; again, you don't initialize `a` so it doesn't point to any valid integer, and so `scanf` writes to a random place in memory.  Perhaps you meant to write `int a;` and `scanf("%d", &a);`.  It might be good to brush up your pointers skills before attempting something more advanced like threads.

Comment: I want to pass the values from main() to the thread i.e. printSum()

Comment: Typically you would define a struct to contain the thread-local parameters that you need to pass. You would then roll the struct from `main()` and pass the struct to the thread worker function as the 4th argument to `pthread_create`. And you would use an argument in `printSum`.

Comment: `int *a,*b,*add;printf("Enter first number: ");scanf("%d",*&a);` Where does the memory of `a` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, main begins as the first thread, then pthread_create() creates a new thread, so now we have two threads. The problem here is that the program finishes before the new thread finishes its operation, it is missing pthread_join() to make main() wait for print_Sum() to be done with its tasks. Furthermore, you have provided pointers, but no memory for them, I have decided to create a struct to pass the numbers into the thread (the last parameter of pthread_create()), then cast arg as that struct.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *printSum(void *arg);

struct portions {
        int a;
        int b;
};

int main(void)
{
        struct portions a;
        printf("Enter first number: ");
        scanf("%d",&a.a);
        printf("Enter second number: ");
        scanf("%d",&a.b);


        pthread_t thread;
        pthread_create(&thread, NULL, printSum, &a);
        pthread_join(thread, NULL);
        return 0;
}

void *printSum(void *arg)
{
        struct portions *a = (struct portions *)arg;
        int add;

        add = a->a + a->b;
        printf("Sum = %d", add);
}
```

Comment: "the problem here is ..." that is _not_ the primary problem. "you have provided pointers, but no memory for them" -- that _is_.

Answer (score 0):

```
        int *a,*b,*add;
        printf("Enter first number: ");
        scanf("%d",*&a);
```

You have not allocated any memory for `a`.
Also that `*&a`<==>`a`.